# Sharing data between different partial views on same index in asp.net with razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have razor view with folowing structure:

[image]

Partial view A is filtering partial view B. Partial view B is filtering Partial View C.
Partial View D is filtering Partial View E.

Partial view C then opens jQuery UI dialog with form to enter data in table shown in partial view E.

My problem here is how to send data from partial D to partial C?

Views A, B and C are accessing controller A and viewmodel X, views D and E are accessing controller B and viewmodel Y.
 Views A and D are loaded simoultaneosly when page is loaded first time, and they are with fixed values.

Partial views A, B and C are also shared views.

Here is code for index.cshtml:

```
@model WebApplication3.ViewModels.projekatViewModel
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rad sa projektima";
}

<h2>Rad sa projektima</h2>
<div id="dialog-edit"></div>
<div id="mainWrap">
    <div id="mainLeft">
        <div id="pKNormativa">
            <div id="KnjigeNormativa">@Html.Partial("A", Model, null)</div>
        </div>
        <div id="pGrupe">
            <div id="GrupeRadova"> @Html.Partial("B", Model, null)</div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="mainRight">
        <div id="pPozicije">
            <div id="Pozicije"> @{ Html.RenderPartial("C", Model.pozicije, null); }</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="projectWrap">
    <div id="projects">
        @Html.Partial("D")
    </div>


    <div class="CSSTableGenerator" id="Projekat">
        @Html.Partial("E", Model.projekti)
    </div>

</div>
```

Partial views don't have anything special inside, just a foreach rendering a `<table>` to show data and one ajax.actionlink to call controller and show data on next view in order...

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: C is shown only once and it's calling controller method that need one parameter from C and one from D.

Comment: You can use TempData or Session for that purpose.

Comment: You should post a code snippet showing your controller structure and views. Including how the partials are rendered "simultaneously", are you using `Html.Action`, `Html.Partial` etc...

Answer (score 4):

You could share data between views using the `HttpContext.Items`.

```
@{
    this.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items["Stuff"] = "some-data";
}
```

this data is valid for a single HTTP Request. Also you can share data between a parent view and a partial view.

More info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx

[When can we use HttpContext.Current.Items to stores data in ASP.NET?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146455/When-can-we-use-HttpContext-Current-Items-to-store)

Comment: I was able to pass data from one "call" of a partial view to the subsequent calls using this (from inside the partial view when ViewBad did not work). Cheers

Comment: `ViewContext.TempData` is even better suited for this task.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see your view(s) and how these partials are being called, but you can pass data/models to any partial.  This gets tricky with a designated model for each partial, so sometimes its easier to fall back on ViewData that you can setup from your controller:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/partialA", ViewData["commonPartialData"]);}
```

Comment: that is not a good idea that whole model inside a viewdata.it is comes performanve issue..

Comment: I agree, I wouldn't include a view model in this manner, but simply any common data that is required across the partials as per the above scenario.